# force linked static libraries with cmake not working

Tags: c++, cmake, linker

We have a multi-project cmake setup that includes some `IMPORTED` static libraries. For one of our executables we need to force-link in all symbols in a few of these `IMPORTED` libraries so we need to pass `-Wl,-force_load` to the compiler before the name of that library. Note that there are dependencies between these imported libraries so they need to be placed in the correct order in the link command line. These dependencies are declared in the root `CMakeLists.txt` via `set_target_properties(fake_2 PROPERTIES INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES ...)`.

We were using the fairly standard `target_link_libraries(lib_a PUBLIC -Wl,-force_load fake_4)` but it turns out that cmake treats `-Wl,-force_load` as a fairly arbitrary linker flag and if you apply it to several libraries like:

```
target_link_libraries(lib_a PUBLIC -Wl,-force_load fake_4)
target_link_libraries(lib_a PUBLIC -Wl,-force_load fake_3)
```

it won't necessary apply those linker flags to both `fake_4` and `fake_3`. In some circumstances it'll de-duplicate the flag and apply it to only one of the libraries. Attempts to fix this like

```
target_link_libraries(lib_a PUBLIC "-Wl,-force_load $<TARGET_PROPERTY:fake_4,IMPORTED_LOCATION>")
```

cause the linker flags to be placed before the library, but then cmake doesn't recognize the imported libs for what they are so it ignores the dependencies between them.

A full example project that exhibits these issues can be found here: https://github.com/REVLUTION/cmake-example

Note: this was moved from the [cmake discussion forums](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/wl-force-link-flags-not-working-correctly/322/7) if you'd like to see some of the comments there.

Comment: AFAIK `-force_load` makes seance for dynamic libraries linked to application (by default dll-s are lazy loaded). Static libraries are just become part of executable so there is no separate "load" for them.

Comment: Normally when you link a static library only the symbols that are used in in other code are retained. The `-force_load` tells the compiler to include all the symbols even if they don't appear to be used. This is necessary for things like TensorFlow where the set of functions that will be called can't be known at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filled a bug about this a while back. It's confirmed but still unresolved:

https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20078#note_665095

Answer (score 0):

Edit: as per the comments it looks like this doesn't actually work.

---

The [cake discussion forum](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/wl-force-link-flags-not-working-correctly/322) posted an answer that resolves the issue. I'm reposting it here for easy access.

As Alain Martin says [there](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/wl-force-link-flags-not-working-correctly/322/10):

> I guess that’s because you need both:
>
> - `target_link_libraries(utils_video_encode_decode_ffmpeg PUBLIC avfilter)` for the “regular” dependency
> - `target_link_libraries(utils_video_encode_decode_ffmpeg PUBLIC "-Wl,-force_load $<TARGET_PROPERTY:avfilter,IMPORTED_LOCATION>")` for
>     the “force load”
>
> Putting them together:
>
> ```
> target_link_libraries(utils_video_encode_decode_ffmpeg
>   PUBLIC
>     avfilter
>       "-Wl,-force_load $<TARGET_PROPERTY:avfilter,IMPORTED_LOCATION>"
> )
> ```

Comment: I think that will work most of the time but it’s not guaranteed to work. Let’s assume `avfilter` depends on some other library like `bzip`. cmake will re-order the plain `avfilter` linking to ensure that `avfilter` comes before `bzip` on the link line so that the symbols it needs from bzip get linked. But nothing is using `avfilter` so the linker drops all its symbols and thus all the `bzip` symbols as well. In short "-l/usr/lib/avfilter -lbzip -Wl,-force_load -l/usr/lib/avfilter` doesn’t work and there’s nothing to guarantee this won’t happen.

Comment: Turns out there's a 2nd issue with this solution: if you do use some symbols from the library but not others you get a duplicate symbols error at link time because the first link retains the symbols you do use and the 2nd, force-link then re-defines them.